# LAN networking problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I have 7 PC with Ubuntu 14.04 on them. I want one PC be like server (i have lampp on this and it works but only on that PC), I want all to conect together using switch no router. So they can acces server computer.

```
                                           ---PC1
                                          ----PC2
SERVER ------------ SWITCH ------------- -----PC3
                                          ----PC4
                                           ---PC5
                                             -PC6
```

and help is very useful!

Comment: @KasiyA is there a reason their statement is offtopic here?  They want to turn one of their Ubuntu systems into a server with DHCP, IP routing, and a LAMP stack.

Comment: @ThomasW. No I just think He/She can get fast answer there. I didn't flag it here.

Comment: @KasiyA I don't think it's 100% necessary to redirect people to other sites all the time, in this case you might be right but still.  I'd reword your comment next time to say "Ask it on serverfault, and you might get a faster response." rather than just say "Ask it on serverfault"

Comment: Ok you are right

Comment: I posted it on serverfault too!

Answer (score 0):

I found what you are looking for here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dhcp.html
 if you need more help. let me know.

Comment: i know it says 12.04, but its the same in 14.04 as well